# postgres query exclude search criteria by parameter

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and 4 columns there. Also I pass 4 parameters to my query. For example, if I pass only one parameter equals true, I want only first column to take part is query

sth like

```
select * from mytable where (case when @mypar=true then **and field1=1** end)
```

I want **AND** clauses to be included by parameter. How to do that in postgres?

Comment: It is very simple with dynamic SQL - construct query in variable and run it using `execute`. By the way - PostgreSQL allows to have CASE command in WHERE part also in plain SQL you just have to have `and` outside of case and have also else condition - for example like this `WHERE condition1 and case when ... then ... else 1=1 end`

Comment: Ok thanks but dynamic SQL is not an option in the project. Also, your approach with case when is also doesn't work for me because I want to completely exclude all other fields except needed ones. So I have 4 boolean columns. I want to search  by 1 column, or two or 4 or 0. But spring JPA doesn't allow to use dynamic sql filters. So I thought to do that in one query. Thanks